# CSS "absolutely" positioned border-image

Tags: hover, absolute, css

I have a CSS design problem for a day and a halve now and it is driving me nuts. I have an horizontal navigation bar with a single unordered list inside. Each list item contains an anchor (or hyperlink) to a page within the website, the CSS is as follows:

```
nav#main{
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
nav#main ul{
    list-style:none;
}
nav#main li{
    float:left;
    display: block;
    overflow:auto;
}
nav#main a{
    display:block;
    padding:1em;
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1.6em;
}
nav#main a:hover{
    background:#EF7E05;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    border-width:0 0 15px 0;
    border-image:
        url('../images/nav.png')
        0 
        0
        25
        stretch;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<nav id="main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="contentArea">
    <!-- DIFFERENT DIVS, COLUMS ARTICLES ETC. -->
</div>
```

This works all like it should work.

However what i am trying to accomplish is that the border image is displayed outside the nav bar and that it doesn't push the contentArea downwards a 25px. Any ideas?

I also tried to absolute position a block with a.hover::after. This works beautifully, however the width of the block cannot be set equal to a. Perhaps any ideas on this one too?

Comment: do you have a link? it's hard to picture the issue.. where exactly do you want the border-image to be displayed? out side the navbar but not in the document flow?

Comment: use z-index:2; that should work. [IP address]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WcA2J/ try and edit on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your floated elements using a clear rather than `overflow:visible`

If you do this you can use your absolute positioning to create the border:

```
nav#main{
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
}
nav#main:after {
    content:'';
    display:block; 
    clear:both;
}
nav#main ul{
    list-style:none;
}
nav#main li{
    float:left;
    display: block;
    overflow:visible;
}
nav#main a{
    display:block;
    padding:1em;
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1.6em;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
}
nav#main a:hover{
    background:#EF7E05;
}
nav#main a:hover:after{
    background-clip:padding-box;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0; 
    right:0;
    border-width:0 0 15px 0;
    border-image:
        url('../images/nav.png')
        0 
        0
        25
        stretch;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/He96x/)

I have noticed that the border image thing doesn't work in firefox or ie so this will give you the same effect and is more browser friendly:

```
nav#main a:hover:after{
    background-clip:padding-box;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0; 
    right:0;
    height:15px;
    background: url('../images/nav.png') left top no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 15px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/He96x/6/)

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for your intell! For me it did solve the puzzle completely! Indeed the background option is far better than the border option.